# Guidance with the usage of `gcloud vm instance persistent route`

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, gcloud

Can anyone help with adding persistent routes to VM instances created on GCP?

Specifically with Debian 9 and Ubuntu 16.04. For anyone not familiar, editing the `/etc/network/interfaces` file will not work for example.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-routes#addingroute

Comment: @CloudAce Not trying to add routes to the VPC in GCP.  Talking about persistent routes on Linux VMs instantiated in the cloud.

Comment: @EMP JCR Can you please mark the answer as accepted if it has helped you solving your issue?

Answer (score 3):

Per this [site](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/configuring-static-routes-in-debian-or-red-hat-linux-systems.html) , you can add static route using the IP command (Tested on Debian):

```
ip route add {NETWORK} via {IP} dev {DEVICE}
```

For example network 192.168.55.0/24 available via 192.168.1.254:

```
# ip route add 192.168.55.0/24 via 192.168.1.254 dev eth1
```

Alternatively, you can use old good route command too:

```
route add -net 192.168.55.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.1.254 dev eth1
```

#### Edit

Since the /etc/network/interfaces file gets overwritten at boot-up, simply add the `ip route add` command to the [startup-script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6NJtu.jpg) section of your instance in GCE. This way it will add the route at each boot for persistence. More details [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript).

Go to your instance edit page and click '**add item**' under '**custom metadata**'.
For the **key** section enter `startup-script` and for the **value** section enter `ip route add 192.168.55.0/24 via 10.142.0.1 dev eth0`. Make sure your interface and networks matches your environment in the command. Reboot to test.